# UPDATE table Replace() sub-string returns rows but 0 Changed

Tags: mysql

Im Running the following query to remove the word "Hot Sale" from my product titles in MySql Workbench:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_title = REPLACE (post_title, 'Hot Sale', '')
WHERE 
(post_type = 'product' OR post_type = 'product_variation') 
AND 
(post_title LIKE '%Hot Sale%')
```

But I'm getting Following response the rows remain unchanged

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 9  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: could you show us some example data for that? it should work as wanted see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5cf2cc7469dc2bca609104ee17a4bec4

Comment: That will work if there's an exact match on that text. Remember to take a snapshot of your database before wrecking around with queries like this to avoid having an [onosecond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6NJkWbM1xk) moment.

Comment: Also consider using `post_type IN (?,?)` instead of `post_type=? OR post_type=?`

Comment: This works amazingly well in PHPMyAdmin as well as fiddle, but somehow responds like I mentioned in the question in MySQL Workbench 8.0 as:
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 42  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0